# How to get the second word of a string in SQL for Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to retrieve the second word from a string using Access version of SQL. Since I'm using Access ODBC to build the query I can't use any Access function, just SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to select the second word of a string,if it just one word in the string it will return null, this does assume that words have spaces to differentiate each other.

`SELECT IIF(InStr([YourStringField],' ')=0, '', Mid([YourStringField], InStr([YourStringField],' ')+1,Len([YourStringField]))) as SecondWord
FROM tbl_YourTable`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be messy, but if you wanted a pure SQL approach then this should give you what you need:

```
SELECT Mid([YourStringField],InStr([YourStringField],' ')+1,InStr(Mid([YourStringField],InStr([YourStringField],' ')+1,Len([YourStringField])),' ')-1) as SecondWord
FROM tbl_YourTable
```

Note, this does assume that the 2nd word has a space after it.

Otherwise you could write a UDF and use the Split() function as iDevlop has suggested.

Comment: It didn't work to get the second word, but it guided me in the right direction to find the answer, thank you CrazyHorse!